# Is there a way to know that the node is disconnected/out of the RPL network in contiki 3.0?

Tags: networking, iot, contiki, cooja

I have a mobility node that moved out of the range of the RPL network. I need to know that this node is out of the network range.
I tried this code:

```
if (rpl_neighbor_count() == 0) {
    printf("NO NEIGHBORS\n"); 
}
else {
    printf("There are NEIGHBORS \n");
}
```

However, the count doesn't update when the movement of the node happens and it remains as it was before and it is the same all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The RPL DAG structure `struct rpl_dag` has a member variable `uint8_t joined`. You can call `rpl_get_dag` to get the DAG structure and then look at whether `joined` is 0 or 1.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Because the node was in the network previously it saves and returns always the joined=1.  I wrote this:  ```  rpl_dag_t *dag_table;
   dag_table=rpl_get_dag(&my_ipaddr);
   printf("joined: %u\n", dag_table->joined); ``` . It always gives me 1 even if the node still forever out of the range.

Comment: Ok, you have a point. This seems like a bug in the implementation. Would this work for you: checking `dag->preferred_parent == NULL && dag->rank != ROOT_RANK(dag)` - i.e. there is no preferred parent and the node is not the root?